# How add text in custom theme header magento 2

Tags: magento2, xml, custom-theme

```
 <referenceContainer name="header.wrapper">
          <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header.links" after="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">custom_header_text</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

app/design/frontend/Sm/multe/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

i added in code in magento 2 but not showing in header

Answer (score 0):

Use **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text** class for simple text.

Try following way:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.wrapper">
    <block name="sample_text" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string">Custome Header Text</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml** add below code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="test.link" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">test</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">test</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
   ```
2. Run the below command and check
   **php bin/magento s:s:d -f**

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your xml file

```
<referenceContainer name="header.wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="my_block_name">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">my_cmsblock_identifier</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**"my_cmsblock_identifier"** is a CMS block identifier will created in admin

Answer (score 0):

If we want to add the content on the header right section then we can add the below code in the theme path app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <container name="header-right" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-right">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_name">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_name</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

If we want to add the custom link then we can use the below code in the theme path app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom_link">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">link label</argument>
           <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Url path</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```